# Using too many forms in single page. Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am making admin panel for my website and hence need to show all the rows of the table and with every row, there would be two buttons update and delete.
In this `$users` array is passed from the controller.

At first I was making a request using anchor tag and no forms like:

```
<a href='<?php echo base_url() ?>users/update/<?php echo $user->id ?>'>Update</a>
<a href='<?php echo base_url() ?>users/delete/<?php echo $user->id ?>'>Delete</a>
```

But I realised anyone can make a call by simply changing the parameter so I used POST request using forms like:

```
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $user->name ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $user->email ?></td>
        <td>
            <form method='post' action='<?php echo base_url() ?>users/update'>
                <input type='hidden' name='upd_user_id' value='<?php ehco $user->id ?>'>
                <input type='submit' value='Update'>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method='post' action='<?php echo base_url() ?>users/delete'>
                <input type='hidden' name='del_user_id' value='<?php ehco $user->id ?>'>
                <input type='submit' value='Delete'>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

In this user can easily check the id(which is bad I think) using inspect element but cannot make an unnecessary call, so I think it is a safe approach but this would result in too many forms on one page so I want to know if this is the right thing I am doing here if not what should I do.

**EDIT-1**
This is my delete method in users controller

```
public function delete()
{
    if( $this->input->post("del_user_id") ) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        $user_id_delete  = $this->input->post("del_user_id");
        $this->user_model->delete_user($user_id_delete);
    }
    redirect('users');
    die();
}
```

Comment: Changing something from using GET to using POST doesn't make anything more secure. (I'll ignore ssl for now.)

Comment: Restrict your response controller.

Comment: @JonStirling can you please tell why is that and how to make a secure app except using SSL.

Comment: @HendraNucleo Please tell on what basis should I restrict. only checking if it is null is not enough.

Comment: It depend on your approach and waht you aim. If possible can you post your controller/model handle the request ? Example, if i use ajax, usually in controller i check if request is ajax & if had HTTP_REFERER.

Comment: If the concern is that they might try to update or delete something they shouldn't you need to restrict based on 1.) who they are and 2.) what range of data that user has the right to modify. Presumably they are an admin and have been given a table of items to edit/delete. The back-end needs to double check these criteria are met. If that is in place, who cares if they manually change the URL parameter?

Comment: This is unrelated to the answer. Please consider it a friendly tip. A more effective way to use `base_url()` is `<a href='<?php echo base_url("users/update/$user->id") ?>'>Update</a>`

Comment: @DFriend Thanks for the tip and suggestion, will put a check for admin and rights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do additional checks just before you update or delete. E.g.

```
Where user_id = (_GET or _POST user_id) AND company_id = (Session company ID)
```

OR

```
Where user_id = (_GET or _POST user_id) AND owner_id = (Session user ID)
```

Obviously it will depend on what fields are available in your data table so that if someone do change _GET or _POST values then you are not simply using that parameter only to delete or update, and they are only deleting/updating record which they have already access to.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Thanks, this will surely reduce the number of unwanted calls.

Answer (score 0):

you was right using

```
<a href='<?php echo site_url() ?>users/update/<?php echo $user->id ?>'>Update</a>
<a href='<?php echo site_url() ?>users/delete/<?php echo $user->id ?>'>Delete</a>
```

but i don´t know if your controller is in the right way like

```
class Users extends CI_Controller{
    function update( $user_id = NULL ){
        if( ! is_null($user_id)){
            $result = $this->model->update_model($user_id);

            $this->session->set_flashfata('updated', 'The user was successfully updated');

            redirect('controller/method', 'refresh');
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashfata('error', 'The user can´t be null');

            redirect('controller/method', 'refresh');
        }
    }

    //same as delete
}
```

**you need to specify in the controller/method the parameter that you are sending**

Comment: I forgot to mention, change `base_url()` to `site_url()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive ajax function with jQuery like so:

```
<!-- This is the link tag you can add in your users loop -->
<a href="" class="update" data-user-id="<?php echo $user->id ?>">Update</a>

<!-- Put this script at the end of your page -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".update").on('click', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();

        var $id = $(this).data('user-id');
        var $values = {
            "id"  : $id
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '<?php echo base_url() ?>users/update/',
            data: $values,
            cache: false,
            success: function(){
                console.log('Updated: ' + $id);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });

});
</script>
```